# Explain this `return` statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, return

For context, I'm looking at the npm package `unique-random`. It's just eight lines of code, so, in it's entirety:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (min, max) {
    var prev;
    return function rand() {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        return prev = num === prev && min !== max ? rand() : num;
    };
};
```

I understand most of what's going on, I'm just not quite sure what the final return statement is doing.

Could someone explain it as explicitly as possible (I'm really new to JavaScript and coding generally).

I guess maybe this might be a general question about what's going on in `return` statements that also appear to be *assignments* ? 
Is that right?

So there's a conditional operator. And that says if what's to the left of the `?` is true, then what's to the left of the `:`, else what's to the right of the `:`. So, if `num === prev` and `min !== max`, assign `rand()` to `prev`, else assign `num` to `prev`?

Is that right?

Comment: It creates a random number but checks to see if this random number is the same as last time a random number was generated. If it is in fact the same number as last time, it calls `rand()` again, otherwise it returns `num`.

Comment: you are correct plus what @h2ooooooo ^ said.

Comment: Can someone describe how the `prev = num === num` condition is supposed to work? I don't see how it can evaluate to anything else than `true`

Comment: @Aaron On its own, it would. But the `=` is the last thing evaluated, so actually `prev` gets set to the result of `num === prev && min !== max ? rand() : num`. I agree this isn't really clear and it's not readable code. I have no idea what this module is for looking at it.

Comment: @AndrewTaylor thanks, I thought `=` had high priority, turns out it's one of the lowest. [MDN article on JS operators precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), for those interested.

Comment: @Aaron I've been using JS for years and I don't know the precedencies. I don't plan to learn them: if I can't remember I assume anyone else reading the code can't either so put the brackets in and let the minifier worry about removing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this module returns a function:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return function rand() {
      // stuff
    };
};
```

So when you import this module you have to call what you get:

```
var rand = import('./rand');
rand(); // stuff
```

Then the rand function has two parts:

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
```

Compute a random value between min and max.

```
return prev = num === prev && min !== max ? rand() : num;
```

Ensure the new num is not the same as the previous one, and save the new value in prev you can see it as follow:

```
if ( num === prev && min !== max ){
   prev = rand();
} else {
   prev = num;
}
return prev;
```

I'll add that the `prev` variable is in the module closure, so it's accessible from within the scope of `rand`, so each call to `rand` will have the new `prev` value.

(it's not strictly speaking the same code but it should do the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect example of code that could use brackets.
The same can be written as follows which would make it clearer:

```
return prev = ( num === prev && min !== max )? rand() : num;
```

This includes an assignment and ternary operation ( **x** ? **y** : **z** ), which works exactly as you described. If **x** is true, then **y**, else **z**;

This could all be written as follows which might make it even more clear:

```
if ( num === prev && min !== max ){
  prev = rand();
}
else {
  prev = num;
}
return prev;
```